# VSCode | The editor cannot be opened due to an unexpected error

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Goal: Get regular Bash and Git in Terminal working for Python projects in Visual Studio Code.

Anytime I launch, I see this error. I cannot open code or use Terminal.

[image: Visual Studio Code screen]

Error Message:

```
The editor cannot be opened due to an unexpected error: No file system provider found for resource 'vscode-remote://wsl%2Bubuntu/...'
```

---

**Update:** Uninstalled WSL. I no longer have the below old Terminal output.

Terminal:

```
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.277] Resolving wsl+ubuntu, resolveAttempt: 1
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.361] Starting VS Code Server inside WSL (wsl1)
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.361] Extension version: 0.66.3
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.361] Windows build: 19044. Multi distro support: available. WSL path support: enabled
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.361] No shell environment set or found for current distro.
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.546] WSL daemon log file: 
[2022-06-13 15:53:18.548] Probing if server is already installed: C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -e sh -c "[ -d ~/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5 ] && printf found || ([ -f /etc/alpine-release ] && printf alpine-; uname -m)"
[2022-06-13 15:53:19.023] Probing result: x86_64
[2022-06-13 15:53:19.024] No server install found in WSL, needs linux-x64
[2022-06-13 15:53:19.024] Downloading server on client side to C:\Users\dabell\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-remote-wsl\c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5\vscode-server-stable-linux-x64.tar.gz.
[2022-06-13 15:53:19.024] https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/server-linux-x64/stable
[2022-06-13 15:53:26.719] Unable to download server on client side: Error: Request downloadRequest failed with message: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND update.code.visualstudio.com. Will try to download on WSL side.
[2022-06-13 15:53:26.721] Launching C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu sh -c '"$VSCODE_WSL_EXT_LOCATION/scripts/wslServer.sh" c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5 stable code-server .vscode-server --host=127.0.0.1 --port=0 --connection-token=1433349295-3472956524-2784734323-674824766 --use-host-proxy --without-browser-env-var --disable-websocket-compression --accept-server-license-terms --telemetry-level=all'
[2022-06-13 15:53:27.103] Setting up server environment: Looking for /home/danielbellhv/.vscode-server/server-env-setup. Not found.
[2022-06-13 15:53:27.104] WSL version: 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft Ubuntu
[2022-06-13 15:53:27.104] Updating VS Code Server to version c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5
[2022-06-13 15:53:27.104] Removing previous installation...
[2022-06-13 15:53:27.104] Installing VS Code Server for x64 (c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5)
[2022-06-13 15:53:27.104] Downloading:     
[2022-06-13 15:53:37.329] 100%
[2022-06-13 15:53:37.329] Failed
[2022-06-13 15:53:37.331] --2022-06-13 16:53:37--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/server-linux-x64/stable
[2022-06-13 15:53:37.331] Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)... 
[2022-06-13 15:53:47.093] failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
[2022-06-13 15:53:47.093] wget: unable to resolve host address ‘update.code.visualstudio.com’
[2022-06-13 15:53:47.093] ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/danielbellhv/.vscode-server/bin/c3511e6c69bb39013c4a4b7b9566ec1ca73fc4d5-1655135606.tar.gz
[2022-06-13 15:53:47.094] VS Code Server for WSL closed unexpectedly.
[2022-06-13 15:53:47.094] For help with startup problems, go to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_wsl-tips
[2022-06-13 15:53:47.116] WSL Daemon exited with code 0
```

Comment: This issue has been happening since almost two years to me and I still don't understand why it is happening and why it isn't fixed permanently...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I simply uninstalled and reinstalled WSL 2, from Windows Store.

You can via command line, but I found using Windows Store to be more accessible / user friendly.

Comment: This is not an option for most Enterprises as laptops often has Windows Store Disabled by a domain controller due to security policies.

Answer (score 14):

running `wsl --shutdown` from windows command line and relaunch the vscode solved my issue.

Comment: This worked for me and seems like the most 'correct' solution for the majority of cases.

Comment: I only restarted VScode, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 10):

This can be solved temporarily by restarting the WSL container's network.

Open Powershell as administrator and run the following command:

`Restart-Service LxssManager`

I would advise saving it to a script such as `restart-WSL-network.ps1` and setting up a shortcut to run this when it happens again.

Comment: Yup this worked for me, thanks!   It did also kill my Docker Desktop backend :D

Answer (score 10):

Deleting the .vscode* folders in the home directory (in wsl) fixed the issue

Answer (score 5):

I'm kind of late to the party, but I've just had this issue today. I only restarted Windows, and now it works fine!

Comment: In my case only restarting windows did help.  Also, try to check if Pycharm has access to this project, as this was the error only in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

Tried shutting down WSL using `wsl --shutdown` and restarting vs code, but it still didn't work.

What i had to do was also close other vs code instances and ensure VS code was not running in the background. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Something was hung for me. Couldn't restart wsl, so restarted the PC, made sure wsl is running, then docker if you are using docker and vscode opens fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, caused by a broken installation of Ubuntu; basically, the Ubuntu installation was forcibly aborted, but some configuration still remained and I could see the distro listed by the `wsl --list` command.

I manually unregistered the distro, issuing the following command in Powershell:

```bash
wsl --unregister Ubuntu
```

Afterwards, I also checked `wsl --list` to be sure that:

1. the offending distro was not present any more and
2. that the default distro was correct)

Then everything started to work properly again.